# Same column width across multiple rows CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a simple div with 3 columns and 2 rows arranged as such using css grid:

```
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: fit-content(100px) auto fit-content(100px);
}

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">A</div>
    <div class="child">BBBBB</div>
    <div class="child">C</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">A</div>
    <div class="child">BBBBB</div>
    <div class="child">C</div>
</div>
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

First column (A) should simply be the width of the content
First column (C) should simply be the width of the content
First column (BBBB) should take the remaining available space

The above I can accomplish using the css above.  However I need to make the grid behave like a table, so that the width of each column is made equal across all rows.

For example, if the width of column A in the first row is larger than than column A in the 2nd row, the all rows should take the largest column width.

Is this possible?  I'm open to using flexbox if it is not possible with css-grid, but cannot use tables.

Comment: *I need to make the grid behave like a table* --> you have your answer, use a table layout (no need to change the html)

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious solution is to make it a single grid

```css
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: fit-content(100px) auto fit-content(100px);
    width: 500px;
}

.child {
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">A</div>
    <div class="child">BBBBB</div>
    <div class="child">C</div>
    <div class="child">A</div>
    <div class="child">BBBBB</div>
    <div class="child">C</div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, create a container that is a grid, and make parent a subgrid. Only limited browser support by now.

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: fit-content(100px) auto fit-content(100px);
}

.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-column: span 3;
    grid-template-columns: subgrid;
    width: 500px;
}

.child {
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">A</div>
    <div class="child">BBBBB</div>
    <div class="child">C</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">A</div>
    <div class="child">BBBBB</div>
    <div class="child">C</div>
</div>
</div>
```